# How can I put a partial view of one type into a regular view of another type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to put a partial view in a regular view that is not of the same type. I create the partial view from my Assignment model and put it in the /Views/Shared folder. Then I tried to call the partial view in a regular view that was based on another model (InstructorIndexData ) and got the error message:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SchoolIn.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SchoolIn.Models.Assignment'.

Here’s a bit of code from the partial view:

```
@model ...Models.Assignment
<div class="display-label">Grade</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Grade)
</div>
```

And here’s a bit of code from the regular view:

```
@model SchoolIn.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData


<td> @Html.Partial("_UpdateAttendance")</td>
```

How can I put a partial view of one type into a regular view of another type?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: My partial view is in the Shard folder like this:~/Views/Shared/_UpdateAttendance.cshtml.  In the regular view I'm trying to do @Html.Partial("_UpdateAttendance").  Sorry I didn't add that bit earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering the view using the `Html.Partial` method you could pass the model as second argument:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialName", item.Grade)
```

If you are using display/editor templates, this is done automatically:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Grade)
```

Now assuming that the Grade property is of type `Assignment`, then the `~/Views/Shared/DislpayTemplates/Assignment.cshtml` will be rendered.

If on the other hand you have a collection property:

```
public IEnumerable<Assignment> Grades { get; set; }
```

then you could use:

```
@model SchoolIn.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData
<table>
    <tr>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Grades)
    </tr>
</table>
```

and now the `Assignment.cshtml` display template will automatically be rendered for each element of the Grades collection so that you don't have to write any ugly loops in your view.